# Regexp underscore infront of capital letters

Tags: php, regex, string

I created this regexp that will add an underscore infront of all capital letters except for the first one if it's in the beginning of the string

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?!^)[A-Z]/', '_$0', $string);
// Hello --> Hello
// HelloHello --> Hello_Hello
// aHelloHello --> a_Hello_Hello
// HELLO --> H_E_L_L_O
// hello --> hello
// HHEllo --> H_Hello
```

I would like the regexp to skip all continuous capital characters at the beginning of the string:

```
// HHello --> HHello
// HEllO --> HEll_O
// aHEllo --> a_H_Ello
// HHHHHHHHHHellO --> HHHHHHHHHHell_O
```

In short: a regexp that adds an underscore infront of all capital letters but ignores all continuous capital letters from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
^[A-Z]+(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Z]
```

Replacement string:

```
_$0
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yM0hT2/2)

If you want to done the samething in python then you need to use `regex` module which allows quantifiers in a lookbehind,

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.sub(r'(?<!^[A-Z]+|^)([A-Z])', r'_\1', 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHeLLO')
>>> m
'HHHHHHHHHHHHHe_L_L_O'
```

Comment: This seems to do it perfectly, could you describe me how this words. The regexp looks weird to me. I'll grant you the correct answer soon. :)

Comment: Sorry I posted it from my mobile.what the regex actually do is, it skips all the continuous capital letters at the start and matches other capital letters.

Comment: Yeah I tested it and it works beautifully, I would like to know what the (*SKIP) and (*F) does, these are unfamiliar commands for me.

Comment: How can this be done in python re.As *SKIP and *F functions are in perl and not in python?

Comment: @vks op added the tag php for this question. PHP supports PCRE library.

Comment: i know but is there a way to do this through python?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanna do:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]/', '_$0', $string);
```

Comment: Yeah I don't want the first underscore. Underscores are allowed only on capital letters which are on the right side of the first lowercase letter.

Comment: That comment, combined with that capitals after each other shouldn't get an underscore, makes me believe you effectively want an underscore between every lowercase and uppercase letter. Changed my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but how about:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', $string);
```

Comment: This almost works, "HHellO" becomes "HHell_O" as it skips the double capitals in the beginning, but if you do "heLLo" it becomes "he_LLo" when it should be "he_L_Lo". It should skip continuous capitals only at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I have no idea why stackoverflow hide the underscore in the "heLLo" example, the space is an underscore.